# Getting missing component error in a VB6 application

Tags: vb6, error-handling

I have a VB6 app that has a ton of 3rd party components.  The app works well, but on exit (and only when running as a standalone EXE, e.g. not in the IDE), it pops up an error message:

[image]

I've seen errors like these before but typically it says which component is missing dependencies or is not registered properly.

I ran it through Process Monitor and got the following files that it cannot find:

[image]

And then it quits.  I googled the file names that it cannot find and can't seem to find anything.  It seems like its searching for a variation of MSComENU, MSComEN and MSCOENU dlls.

I checked and rechecked to make sure that all the the 3rd party components are there and they are - the application functions fine, it wouldn't if they weren't there.

It is worth noting that error occurs after the last line of VB6 code (in `Form_Unload` event) has fired.  I know this because the last line is a message box that does appear.

**Much, much later EDIT**: I finally got back to dealing with the problem and figured it out by process of elimination (and it was a loooong process).  In the end it had nothing to do with any MSCOMM*.dll entries.  In fact, I do not know why they still show up in Process Monitor.  The problem was much simpler.

I had several 3rd party controls on the main form.  In an effort not to pollute the main form with a ton of event handling code, I delegated these controls to a new class, like so:

```
' declaration code in main form'
Private WithEvents moDelegateObject as clsDelegateObject

' still in the main form, after initialization'
Set moDelegateObject = new clsDelegateObject
With moDelegateObject
    Set .ThirdPartyCtlHandler1 = me.ThirdPartyCtl1
    Set .ThirdPartyCtlHandler2 = me.ThirdPartyCtl2
    Set .ThirdPartyCtlHandler3 = me.ThirdPartyCtl3
end with

' declarations and properties inside of clsDelegateObject'
Private WithEvents moThirdPartyCtlHandler1 as ThirdPartyCtl
Private WithEvents moThirdPartyCtlHandler2 as ThirdPartyCtl
Private WithEvents moThirdPartyCtlHandler3 as ThirdPartyCtl
Public Event FooEvent() ' other various events as well '

Public Property Set ThirdPartyCtlHandler1(o as ThirdPartyCtl) 
    moThirdPartyCtlHandler1 = o
End Property 
Public Property Get ThirdPartyCtlHandler1() as ThirdPartyCtl
    ThirdPartyCtlHandler1 = moThirdPartyCtlHandler1 
End Property
' ... Repeat for each handler ...'
```

What was missing was code to explicitly deallocate these objects prior to closing.  This is something that Visual Basic typically does.  So I added the following in the Form_QueryClose in the main form:

```
With moDelegateObject
    Set .ThirdPartyCtlHandler1 = Nothing
    Set .ThirdPartyCtlHandler2 = Nothing
    Set .ThirdPartyCtlHandler3 = Nothing
End with
Set moDelegateObject = Nothing
```

Last line turned out to be superflous, but I threw it in there for completeness sake.  I think it was a combination of delegating controls to a delegate class and receiving events from it in the Main form and using a good number of really obscure 3rd party controls which contributed to this problem. It is probable that the 3rd party control does not cleanly deallocates itself.  Anyway, lesson learned.

Comment: +1. @anonymous close-voter: this is a good question. These problems are hard to diagnose, it's very useful to share expertise.

Comment: Is this problem specific to one computer (the development machine?), or is it repeatable on other computers? Has it just started happening in an app that has been working fine previously?

Comment: Looks to me as if some error occurred (or just a libload failure) in a foreign-language version of MSComm32.dll running on a US English machine/user-session trying to load the error message resource DLL for the US English locale.

Comment: @MarkJ It's repeatable on other computers.  The odd thing is that I have a similar app with exactly identical set of dependencies that installs and runs perfectly fine (the install build draws the dependencies from the same location as well).

Comment: @BobRiemersma Did you mean `MSCOMM32.OCX`?  Because I don't think I reference MSCOMM32.DLL anywhere, nor does MSCOMM32.OCX have dependencies on it.

Comment: Well from the Process Monitor screenshot it sure looks like you are using MSComm32.ocx, and a caption bar saying "TTY Soft Modem" sure looks like a candidate to me!  The use of msimtf.dll makes a language/locale issue even more likely since it part of the Input Method Manager.

Comment: @BobRiemersma So are you saying that the binary is somehow set to a language other than English and that is why its searching for something else?

Comment: It looks like the actual MSComm32.ocx itself has non-English messages compiled into it and it has detected that it is running in a US English session, so it wants to load the MSComENU.dll or something close to use English strings.  So it appears that you have a funky edition of MSComm32.ocx you are using for builds.  If you look in MSComm32.dep on your dev machine you normally see a list of the non-English resource DLLs.

Comment: You mentioned that the error does not appear when you run it from within the IDE? Have you tried running Process Monitor on the IDE version and compared the results? This may give you a clue.

Comment: @PAULDAWG The error occurs after the last known line of the code has executed.

Comment: It is somewhat interesting that it says component "

Comment: @AngryHacker did you ever resolve this? I had this question favorite'd out of curiousity.

Comment: @SpectralGhost Unfortunately not.  The project also got placed on hold, so I haven't really researched anything past Feb 20th or so.

Comment: @SpectralGhost Finally resolved it.  Have a look at the EDIT.

Comment: @MarkJ You might be interested in the resolution.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a DLL_PROCESS_DETACH or CoUninitialize problem. Raymond Chen's blog "The Old New Thing" has a couple of relevant articles:

- [When DLL_PROCESS_DETACH tells you that the process is exiting, your best bet is just to return without doing anything](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/05/10253268.aspx)
- [Do you know when your destructors run? Part 1.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/20/135841.aspx)
- [Quick overview of how processes exit on Windows XP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/05/03/2383346.aspx)
- [How you might be loading a DLL during DLL_PROCESS_DETACH without even realizing it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/01/15/9948740.aspx)
- [The thread that gets the DLL_PROCESS_DETACH notification is not necessarily the one that got the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH notification](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/06/26/9804500.aspx)

As you said these are 3rd party components. You could try to make smaller test cases until the problem disappears to pinpoint the buggy component. You could also try a native code debugger and analyze what code created the error message.

**The simplest solution** however to work around the issue is trying to force a specific load-order of all those components. In the Main() or startup form, try to use some functionality of each 3rd party component in a fixed order. If the bug still appears, change the order until the problem vanishes. That might work.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the list of references in the project file to see if any of those third party files are missing dependencies.  If no dependencies are missing then try registering the files again using [regsvr32](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx).  If any of the regsvr32 commands fail then you may have found the component with missing dependencies.

Comment: Also try unregistering (regsvr32 /u [COMPONENT]) first, before re-registering a component. For me this did the job once.