# Dependecy dll missing or not registered in vb6.6

Tags: vb6

I got error

> "component "Ctllogin1" or one of its depenedncy not correctly
>   registered;a file is missing invalid."

while I'm trying to add login ocx control. I added my ocx file in my application and registered too but could not able to add my control on design page and not visible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting missing component error in a VB6 application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138558/getting-missing-component-error-in-a-vb6-application)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks for giving this solution .But i got solution Reason is third pary dll is can not allow to edit due to licence problem so we have to run VBUSC exe and issue solved.Now am easy to use this component thanks